# Checking if a url is already submitted in database in php

Tags: php, mysql, regex

What i need get done is checking if a url is already submitted in database using php.

I have a database table where i store URLS submitted by users. But i want to check if the urls are already submitted or not in the database before inserting it to the database.
For example,
URLS like http://www.example.com, http://www.example.com/, http://example.com and http://example.com/ should return false if any one of them is already inserted in database as they all are same urls.
I think we can get this done by using regular expression.But i am a little weak in regex so need your help.
thank you

**Edited**

Hello, let's assume if the urls are in array not database just to make clear. I know about the unique key and matching url with the result from database. But here i have a

different question if you look at it carefully.

$urls = array('http://www.example.com/newpage.html', 'http://www.example.com/newpage.html');

case
A user submits a url. suppose http://example.com/newpage.html

Now as  a url http://www.example.com/newpage.html is available in $urls array and  http://www.example.com/newpage.html and http://example.com/newpage.html(userinput without www) are same page so i need a function to check it and return false if the url is available in the array. I hope i clarified my self now.

So it's not checking a domain or making unique key in mysql table for url field i think so far. I think we need to use regExp for it. Any help?

Comment: `www.example.com` and `example.com` are *not* the same URLs.

Comment: but i want to asume they both are same as most of the time are same.

Comment: Try ridding of any trailing `/` before the check. This will make `http://www.example.com/` and `http://www.example.com` match. As for the `www` part, Ben's right. If you're really sure about assuming `www` and nothing are the same, try replacing `www.` with blank when adding any URL. That way, you will have `example.com` instead of `www.example.com` for all the records in your database, letting you match properly.

Comment: in that case what if url is http://www.examplewww.com

Comment: `$url = preg_replace('/http(s?):\/\/www\./i','http${1}://',$url)` then. :3

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what URLs in your question is all about. URLs are resources. If you mean submitting HTTP variables sent by a GET method saved to a database, you can use the value of one of those variables as a primary key for searching in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Like Ben James says, www.example.com and example.com are not the same. Also your meaning of URL is a bit vague.

But if you want to check if the example.com already exists. Just do a count on your database with the like option:

```
select count(*) from table where url like '%.example.com%'
```

Where example.com is extracted from the complete url. If count > 0 the domain is already in the database. You will have to finetune this solution, but I should use something like this.

Comment: @nickf: Basically it breaks on a lot more, that's why I mentioned the finetune. Added a small fix for your issue.

Comment: Also, should example.com/test and example.com/blue be the same? I think not. Adding the request URI to the check should help. So `WHERE \`url\` LIKE '%example.com/test%'`.

Comment: I think that will match if the url is http://example.com/newpage.html also. but it's not the same url. I am not looking to match the same domain site but the urls

Comment: In that case it's not much different. Just use "url = 'www.example.com/whatever/comes/after' OR url = 'example.com/whatever/comes/after'"

Answer (score 0):

The database is a different layer in your application. Regex won't help here, because you will have to check what is inside the database first to be able to use Regex on the resultset.

However, you can just make the column storing the URLs [UNIQUE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html) and use [INSERT IGNORE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html).

From MySql manual

> If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors that occur while executing the INSERT statement are treated as warnings instead. For example, without IGNORE, a row that duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With IGNORE, the row still is not inserted, but no error is issued.

This would still insert *example.com* and *www.example.com* though as they are really different strings. You could use [`parse_url`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to check and prepare them before insertion.

Related:

- http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/169692

Answer (score 0):

Maybe making the field "unique" will help this way mysql will check the value. If you get a return code of 1062 then you'll know that its already in the database.

Of course it may not be a good idea if you have too large number of accounts. And you should check the URL with php that you always insert them in the same way. (like adding or removing 'http://' or www)